# Obtener un valor de un json generado con sweetalert2 segun su indice

Tags: javascript, html5, json, jsonarray, sweetalert2

tengo un código con **javascript** que hace que cuando pulsas un botón aparezca un mensaje de **sweetalert2** diciendo que introduzcas tu usuario y contraseña para registrarte pero cuando completo los campos quiero que en consola se muestre la contraseña. El problema que tengo es que no se como obtenerla. Sweetalert2 me devuelve el json así: `["nombre","contraseña"]` y no se como obtener el segundo valor ya que no tiene ningún nombre.

Comment: Deberías añadir un ejemplo mínimo con el código fuente que tienes. Si lo que te devuelve es un arreglo puedes acceder al segundo elemento indexando a `datos[1]` si lo que te devuelve es una cadena de texto en formato JSON deberás parsear esta cadena con `JSON.parse()` y después acceder al dato como te dije unos caracteres antes.

Comment: Ya lo he hecho y me da `["usuario","contraseña"]` y si escribo `datos[1]` me da `"` y si pongo `datos[0]` me da `[`.

Comment: Intentastes usar `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Si y me devuelve ["usuario","contraseña]

Answer (score 0):

Ya funciona. Fue un error en el código que hacia que si los campos no cumplían las condiciones de estar vacíos el json se convirtiera en texto para mostrarlo pero se me olvido poner el `!`